# Borel-Cantelli Lemma for poisson distribution

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, borel-cantelli-lemmas

I'm working on the following excersise:

Given $x\in(0,\infty)$ and $0\le\lambda_n\lt x, \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ and the sequence of random variables $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \sim Poi(\lambda_n)$ show that $P[X_n \geq n \text{ for infinite number of n}] = 0$

I wanted to use the Borel-Cantelli Lemma but got stuck. I know there is an error in my calculation since I would suspect the sum being finite. A hint would be appreciated:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P\left(X_n \geqslant n\right) & =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1-\underbrace{P\left(X_n<n\right)}_{F_{X_n}(n)} \\
& =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1-\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\lambda_n^k}{k !} e^{-\lambda_m} \\
& =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1-e^{-\lambda_m} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\lambda_n^k}{k !} \\
& \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1-e^{-\lambda_m} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{x^k}{k !} \\
& \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1-e^{-\lambda_m} \cdot e^x \\
& =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1-e^{x-\lambda_m}
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Hint: $\mathbb P(X_n \ge n) \le \frac{\mathbb E[X_n^2]}{n^2}$.

Comment: Thank you @DominikKutek . Can I solve this without the Markov inequality ? My first guess was that the sum will be dominated by an expression like $e^x$ or $x e^x$ .

Comment: Probably yes, but without using $\mathbb P(X_n \ge n) = 1 - \mathbb P(X_n < n)$, because then you have minus sign in front of sth you want to bound from above. You could bound it as follows $\sum_n \mathbb P(X_n \ge n) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-\lambda_n} \sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{\lambda_n^k}{k!} \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!} \sum_{n=1}^k 1 = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{(k-1)!} = xe^x$.